# Question about DispatcherUnhandledException

Tags: c#

The problem in this code is that when it's run and I push "Yes" button, This is shown:

[image]

This means that my application stopped working, I just want it to end.

```
private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            string message = "An unhandled exception has ocurred, do you want close the app?";
            MessageBoxResult currentMB = MessageBox.Show(message, "SomeTitleApp", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);

            if (currentMB == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            { Application.Current.Shutdown(); }
            else
            { e.Handled = true; }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DispatcherUnhandledException isn't the right one.  That is only raised when code on the UI thread bombs.  You probably got something going kaboom on a worker thread or before the app even managed to get started.

You have to write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.  Calling Environment.Exit() stops the WER dialog from showing.  Do make sure to log something, nobody much cares for apps that just suddenly flicks out of existence with some traceable reason why.  Log e.ExceptionObject.ToString() to get the exception message and the stack trace recorded.  Often good enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Environment.Exit(0) works, do you have any comment about  Application.Current.Shutdown() ? Why did it fail?

Comment: That's the friendly way to shutdown an app, somebody can wire the Exit event and cancel it.  This is *way* beyond friendly or canceling, your app is dead without a way to revive it.  It suffered a heart attack.  Applying the paddles only works in a TV show.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013.aspx) says:
This method can be called only from the thread that created the Application object. Are you sure you are calling shutdown from the proper thread?

Comment: I like Han's answer. All our code handles both the AppDomain UnHandledException and DispatcherUnhandledException for completeness.